# In which conf file does MariaDB/Galera store the datadir parameter

Tags: mariadb, galera

I've installed a mariaDB Galera cluster version 11.0.3 on Hetzner instances running Debian 11. All goes fine.

For the definitive config I need to setup a dedicated volume for the data and thus change the `datadir` parameter in a configuration file. So far I didn't care very much about it, but I just realized that I can't find an **uncommented** line `datadir = /var/lib/mysql`.in any of the `*.cnf` so that I can change it.

The question is: where is  the `datdadir` parameter defined if it's no in either of

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mariadb_safe.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/60-galera.cnf
```

Or, maybe, is `/var/lib/mysql` the default value ?

Thanks in advance for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/lib/mysql` is the current default, however you can always check with:

```
mariadbd --help --verbose
```

Take a note at the top of this output the config files read.

To pull out the items in configuration files:

```
my_print_defaults --mariadbd
```

On a running system:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
```

Or for datadir directly:

```
SELECT @@datadir;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just to be sure I get your point: if `datadir`  is not defined, the default data directory will be `/var/lib/mysql`, right? And if I define `datadir`to be something else in `50-server.cnf` (where it is currently defined but commented) in all of my galera nodes, the galera cluster will use that place ?

Comment: Yes a default is used. The file where it is doesn't matter, as long as its under a server group (from --help --verbose - `[mysqld]`  `[server]`  `[mysqld-11.1]` `[mariadb]` `[mariadb-11.1]` `[mariadbd]` `[mariadbd-11.1]` `[client-server]` `[galera]`)